# Removing rows with value repeated anywhere in a spreadsheet Excel

Tags: excel, vba

I've been trying to delete rows that have repeated values in different rows and in different columns (defined by the user). I just started learning VBA so I haven't been able do to anything.

For example, if the criteria was finding repeated values in either columns A or B

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   2   7   8   U
3   4   7   8   U
8   1   8   7   W
6   3   8   7   U
5   5   7   8   W
```

It should remove either row 1 or 3 because "1" appears in A or B, and remove either row 2 or 4 because "3" appears in A or B. Row 5 shouldn't be removed because "5" appears both in A and B. I expect it to look like this:

```
A   B   C   D   E
1   2   7   8   U
6   3   8   7   U
5   5   7   8   W
```

I would appreciate any help. Thank you very much

Comment: This doesn't seem to make sense. What's the purpose of this? Why do you not remove either Row 1 or Row 4 since "2" appears in both? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Which row would you want to move, for sure? You say remove *either* 1 or 3. ...which would it be?

Comment: @AAA you're right. I made a mistake. I have edited to make it more clear.
I'm tidying up a database where both A and B are columns of cellphone numbers, and I need to keep just one row associated with each phone number.

Comment: @BruceWayne I doesn't matter which one. I just need to remove one of them.

Comment: Honestly, I would put this in the database as-is then clean it up in there. You can do, in your database, `SELECT * FROM yourtable WHERE columnA IN (SELECT columnB from yourTable);` and identify your duplicates pretty darned quick. An RDBMS is made for this kind of stuff. If you are stuck with excel though, then just do a `=countif(A:A, B1)` and copy down. Delete any row that isn't 0. Much easier then coding this out in a language you don't write in.

Comment: @JNevill, neither of those wouldn't work because then the last row in the OP's example would be deleted and shouldn't be.

Comment: @HelberSantiagoPadillaRocha, try the answer below? If it worked, you should say so.

Answer (score 0):

```
Sub Macro1()

Dim rngA As Range, rngB As Range, LastRow As Long, i As Long, x As Variant

With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets(1)
    LastRow = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngA = .Range("A1:A" & LastRow)
    Set rngB = .Range("B1:B" & LastRow) 'assuming both columns have same number of rows
End With

For i = LastRow To 1 Step -1
    x = Application.Match(rngA(i), rngB, 0)
    If Not IsError(x) Then
        If x <> i Then rngA(i).EntireRow.Delete
    End If
Next i

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need VBA.  You can do this with the `Advanced Filter` using Formula Criteria.

The data table needs a header row

The formula criteria are:

```
A2:  =SUMPRODUCT(--(A10=Sheet1!$B$10:$B$14))=0
A3:  =A10=B10
```

**Before**

[image]

**Dialog**

[image]

**After**

[image]

If you don't want to filter in place, there is an option to have the output in a separate range in the Dialog.

IF I were going to use a VBA solution, I'd probably use a Dictionary to collect the rows of interest, and then spit them on a results range/sheet

This is one way of doing it.

For the price of more complex coding, this algorithm can be sped up considerably, by using VBA arrays in the code.  But I chose the simpler path to demonstrate.  I'd use the more complex method only if this method proves too slow.

This algorithm assumes the source table starts in A9, but you can change that easily.

It also retains the first that doesn't meet the exclusion criteria, whereas the advanced filter method retains the last row.  Either can be modified to work the opposite way.

```
Option Explicit
Sub filterMatchesAB()
    Dim rSrc As Range, C As Range, rRes As Range
    Dim wsSrc As Worksheet, wsRes As Worksheet
    Dim myDict As Object, myKey As Variant
    Dim I As Long

Set wsSrc = Worksheets("sheet1")
Set wsRes = Worksheets("sheet2")
    Set rRes = wsRes.Cells(1, 1)

With wsSrc
    Set rSrc = .Range(.Cells(9, 1), .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp)).Resize(columnsize:=5)
End With

Set myDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
For Each C In rSrc.Rows
    myKey = C.Cells(1, 1)
    If Not myDict.exists(C.Cells(1, 2).Value) Then
        myDict.Add Key:=myKey, Item:=C
    End If
Next C

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
I = 0
For Each myKey In myDict.keys
    I = I + 1
    myDict(myKey).Copy rRes(I, 1)
Next myKey

End Sub
```

Comment: Can you please explain `=SUMPRODUCT(--(A10=Sheet1!$B$10:$B$14))=0`? Never used this before.

Comment: @AAA  `A10=Sheet1!$B$10:$B$14` returns an array of `{True,False}` depending on if the value in `A10` is found in `B10:B14`.  The double unary converts that to `{1,0}` and `SUMPRODUCT` adds them up.  To not filter the result, we want that value to be zero.  Also check Excel HELP for the Advanced Filter as regard using formulas for a criteria; and also using `Multiple criteria, one column, any criteria true`